# res.sendFile, res.download PDF File

Tags: node.js, pdf, sendfile

I have currently a problem to `fetch my pdf` from the **backend** to the **front-end**.
I'm using NodeJS.

I have all my `pdf made with Puppeteer` and saved on a PDF directory.

I'm trying to fetch these `PDF for the front-end`. (for download)

I'have tried with res.sendFile and res.download (res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"/path"), res.download(path.join(__dirname,"/path))

This is the response from the front-end:

```
{data: "%PDF-1.4↵%����↵1 0 obj↵<</Creator (Chromium)↵/Prod…e 7↵/Root 6 0 R↵/Info 1 0 R>>↵startxref↵675↵%%EOF", status: 200,...}
```

I can't download this files.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi1CO.png)

Code from back-end :

```
try { 
    res.download( path.join(__dirname, '/PDF/sofianddes.pdf'), (err) => { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        } 
    });
} catch (err) {}
```

Someone could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting to happen in the front-end?  A PDF file is a binary file, it's not something you can directly look at the raw data.  You have to feed it to a PDF viewer to view it.

Comment: Download the file into pdf when the client click on a button for example

Comment: You should also verify that the PDF file you have saved on the server is valid.  Try loading it into a PDF viewer directly from the file system on your server to verify that the PDF file you have there is valid.

Comment: You should be using `res.download()` then if you want the browser to prompt the user to save the file to their file system.

Comment: When i use res.download() nothing appear

Comment: try {
    res.download(path.join(__dirname, '/PDF/sofianddes.pdf'), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {}

Comment: nothing appears

Comment: If you're trying to ask a question about a specific piece of code you tried, then please put that exact code in your question.

Comment: Done, i'have edit it

Comment: I receive the same object with res.download()